# How can I draw two triangles colored by vertex in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to work on an example problem that requires me to draw two different triangles, each colored by vertex, like this:
[image]

I'm almost there, but there seems to be something off. Here is my result:
[image]

The problem is, the left triangle is the way I intended it to be: three colors, RGB, one per vertex. I don't know how the second one got those colors. My intention was to use the same color vector in the two of them - although I'd appreciate it if someone told me how to use two different color vectors `fColor` so I can define different colors for each of them. I don't know how the right triangle got those colors. They aren't even the same set of colors I defined to the left one. Here are the shaders code that go into the HTML:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    # version 300 es

    in vec4 vPosition;
    in vec4 vColor;
    out vec4 fColor;
    void main()
    {
        fColor = vColor;
        gl_Position = vPosition;
    }

</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    # version 300 es

    precision mediump float;

    in vec4 fColor;
    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main()
    {
        fragColor = fColor;
    }

</script>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
window.onload = function init()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    if (!gl) { alert( "WebGL 2.0 isn't available" ); }

    //
    //  Initialize our data for a single triangle
    //

    // First, initialize the  three points.

    var vertices = [vec3(-1,-1,0),
        vec3(-0.5, 1, 0),
        vec3(0, -1, 0),
        vec3(0,-1,0),
        vec3(0.5, 1, 0),
        vec3(1,-1,0)];

    var colors = [vec3(1,0,0), vec3(0,1,0), vec3(0,0,1)];
    //
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // Load the data into the GPU

    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    var cBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    // Redefine buffer for the vertices and colors
    var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,3,3);
};
```

I'm sorry for the code part being so long, but I'm new to GLSL (and javascript/html for that matter), and I don't know where the error could be, so I posted the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl.vertexAttribPointer` specifies an array of vertex attributes. It also associated the buffer which is currently bund to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` target to the attribute. Therefore, you need to make sure that the correct buffer object is bound when specifying the vertex attributes:

```js
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
// [...]

gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); // bufferId is currently bound
// [...]

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBufferId);
// [...]

gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); // cBufferId is currently bound
// [...]


gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
// [...]

                                                 // bufferId is currently bound
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBufferId);       // therfore you have to bind cBufferId
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
// [...]
```

However, since you want to draw the vertices from 3 to 6, you have also to specify the color attributes for 3 to 6:

```js
var colors = [vec3(0,1,0), vec3(1,0,0), vec3(0,1,0),
              vec3(0,0,1), vec3(1,0,0), vec3(0,0,1)];
```

Specify 1 vertex buffer and 1 color buffer

```js
var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

var cBufferId = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBufferId);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);
```

Draw both tringles separately:

```js
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

```js
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 3, 6);
```

or at once

```js
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had to put everything again in buffer before drawing the second triangle, but I think I'm starting to understand how it works now.

Comment: I was just trying to add one more triangle and colors now. Should I just add more vertices and colors to the respective arrays?